# gsub extracting a specific number from a string regex optional comma

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I need to extract a specific number from strings in a vector that look like this:

```
V1    V2    info
XX    YY    AB=414312;CD=0.5555;EF=1234;GH=2346;IJ=551;AA_CD=0.4633
VV    ZZ    AB=1093;CD=0.4444,0.78463;EF=1654;GH=6546;IJ=1241;AA_CD=0.4366
```

I only want to extract the number from "CD=XXX" (notice there is also a "AA_CD=XXXX" in every row)

I currently have:

```
df$info <- as.numeric(gsub("^.*;CD=[0-9, ],?|;.*$", "", df$info))
```

Which grabs the number after "CD=" in instances where there is not more than one number separated by a comma.

I need this to include the rows in which there are more than one number separated by commas.
My regex only works for rows in which there is only one number in that spot, like so:

```
0.5555
0.4444,0.78463
0.0123
0.34,0.54,0.765
```

I know it is probably a silly mistake I am making...Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Help us help you by making it easy to reproduce a vector or data frame like the one you want to parse. From your first snippet, it's not clear how your data are structured.

Comment: apologies. the two lines listed above represent two rows from one vector. will make adjustment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach

```
lapply(strsplit(gsub("^.*;CD=(0\\.[0-9]),?|;.*$", "\\1", vec), ","), as.numeric)

gsub("^.*;CD=(0\\.[0-9]),?|;.*$", "\\1", vec) #extracts the numbers
#output
1] "0.5555"         "0.4444,0.78463"
```

these are then split at `,` with `strsplit` producing a list

then `as.numeric` converts the list elements with `lapply`

if it is not needed to keep track of which vector member had which numbers:

```
as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(gsub("^.*;CD=(0\\.[0-9]),?|;.*$", "\\1", vec), ",")))
```

Comment: Perfect. as I need to keep the numbers from splitting at the comma, the gsub alone was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!